# Duncan3dc blade duplicate

Tags: php, laravel-blade

i have a a little problem.

in my php site (I do not use laravel but a personal framework) I use duncan3dc blade and the files are so composed:

dir themeComponents

```
  layout.blade.php
         @include('themeComponents.head')
          @yield('content')
         @include('themeComponents.footer')

  head.blade.php
         <DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
         <head></head>
          <body>

  footer.blade.php
          </body>
         </html>

 index.blade.php
        @extends('themeComponents.layout')
        @section('content')
           Hello world!!
        @endsection
```

why, my source code is duplicate?

> Hello world!!
>
> Hello world!!

thx su much
Dany

Comment: There's nothing wrong with those templates, the issue must be with your PHP code calling make/render